# Piccasso 502 Bad Getway

Tags: android, picasso

I use `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2` library for downloading images. I develop client-server application and replace api from one server to another one. All is fine but I faced with one issue all images stop downloading through Picasso library and always return in exception block "502 Bad Getway".

My code:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                    .listener(new Picasso.Listener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
                        {
                            //exception.getMessage() always return "502 Bad Getway"
                        }
                    });
            builder.build().load("http://cifrosvit.com/images/mod_catalog_prod_11/117026/97290_small.jpg")
                    .error(R.mipmap.ic_no_image)
                    .into(holder.image);
```

This is url work through browser and return request code 200.

My issue in git repository https://github.com/coulddog6/PicassoTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/seotm/picassotest/FullscreenActivity.java

Comment: Have you tried loading other pictures that are not in that server? for example, google a random image then try to load it.

Comment: Yes. All other pictures loaded fine. For example: http://cifrosvit.seotm.biz/images/mod_catalog_prod_11/119886/14593343280_cmszoom_height_126.jpeg That image loaded correctly.

Comment: I slove this issue. Case is the server change url to mobile version url. And therefore images download from browser correctly and do not loaded from phone.